# Would this be considered a valid proof for $\forall r \in R$ if $0 < r < 1 $, then $\frac{1}{r(1-r)}\geq 4$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I need to prove that

> $\forall r \in R$ if $0 < r < 1 $, then $\frac{1}{r(1-r)}\geq 4$

using a proof by contra-positive, which was different from the direct proof that the solutions provided.

The proof was as follows: Assume $\frac{1}{r(1-r)} < 4$

case 1: $r>0,(1-r)<0$, then $r>1$.

case 2: $r<0,(1-r)>0$, then $r<0$.

Hence, from the two possibilities of outcomes for $r$, it is either $r>1$, $r<0$

Would this be considered a valid proof ? If not, how would one do so by contrapositivity ?

Comment: Why are those the only two cases?  What about case 3.  $r>0,\;(1-r)>0$?

Comment: Oh right, would the best case just be to do a direct proof then ?

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you are missing 2 cases in your proof by contradiction. Namely:

case 3: $r<0,(1-r)<0$, then $r<0$ (**contradiction**),

case 4: $r>0,(1-r)>0$, then $0<r<1$.

It is this last case that needs more attention. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{n(1-n)}$  >= 4

$\frac{1}{n(1-n)}$ - 4 >= 0

$\frac{1 - 4n(1-n)}{n(1-n)}$ >= 0

$\frac{4n^2 - 4n + 1}{n(1-n)}$ >= 0

$\frac{(2n-1)^2}{n(1-n)}$ >= 0

Since $(2n-1)^2 >= 0$, you are interested only in $n(1-n)>0 $. The solutions of this Inequation are $n ∈ (0, 1)$ and this is the proof.